# Why isn't the variable and its content visible in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Okay I've tried multiple iterations of this code and its not working, I see [object Object] in the H3 tag

This is going to be fundamentally obvious and I'm just missing a core point, I've been scanning stack but can't seem to find why this is happening

So I need the item thats being retrieved from the year ID to be displayed inside the H3 tag, I used the alert function as a test to ensure the value from year was being taken correctly and it is

I've tried

```
var age ={};
    function ageinyear() {
        age = document.getElementById("year").value;
        var agetest = age;
    }</script>


<h3 id="userWelcome"><span id="splitColorHeading">
    Welcome <script> document.write(agetest)</script>,</span> to THE SESH</h3>
```

No dice

```
var age;
    function ageinyear() {
        age = document.getElementById("year").value;
    }</script>


<h3 id="userWelcome"><span id="splitColorHeading">
    Welcome <script> document.write(age)</script>,</span> to THE SESH</h3>
```

**EDIT: I declared both variables inside the function as well as outside, both trying to make them global
Flexing my minuscule brain cells is this possibly due to no return statement, if so added one where I believed it would fit, still no luck**

Still nothing,

Can anyone help a beginner out possibly showing and example or show me with my code what I'm missing as well as an explanation why

Many thanks!

More code:

```
<div id="overlay">
<div id="text">Are you over 18 years old?</div>
<div id="off"><button onclick="off(), ageinyear()">Submit</button></div>
<div id="test"><form>
    <label>
        Name
        <input id="name" name="lblname" type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>
        Age
        <input id="year" name="lblyear" type="text" />
    </label>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to display in your html a value you have in your javascript function or the opposite?

Comment: @Foxhound , can you post your year

Comment: You're trying to write the value to the page before anything has called your function or in any way set that value.  Instead of trying random bits of syntax and hoping for the best, take a step back and define the logic of what it is you're actually trying to do.  Which is... what?

Comment: When do you call `ageinyear` ?

Comment: @edkeveked Yes I want to display an item held in a Javascript variable in a lone of HTML, the value originally came from the HTML

Comment: Nothing actually calls the `ageInYear()` function.

Comment: @Pointy Please explain :)

Comment: @Foxhound it would help seeing this variable (Object Literal maybe? var `obj={...}`) and where and what from this HTML is.

Comment: You have a function called `ageInYear()`. The function is never invoked, so the code in it never runs.

Comment: You also didn't include this other element that has the year value in it, so it's hard to say for sure whether it will work anyway.

Comment: @Pointy check edit at bottom

Comment: It seems to me you are getting all the timing and triggering wrong. I am assuming you want the user to input their year of birth and have your page display the age. You need a function that calculates the age (as you have done) but also then displays it using `innerHTML`. And then you need something that detects when a user actually has entered a year and triggers that function.

Comment: OK, so the function is called when the button is clicked. Thus the value is not available when the `document.write()` code runs.

Comment: @Pointy so the code as stands works minus the triggering/order

Comment: @Foxhound: What is `off()`?  And I doubt you can separate statements by a *comma* like that.  Honestly, it seems like you got stuck on something a while back and have been digging further and further into a rabbit hole of problems, each time hoping that the next piece of dirt you dig below you will somehow return you to the surface.  Start over.  Create your HTML form for the user to provide the value. Then set that form to invoke *one function*. Then in that function, get the value from the form element and write the value to the page where you want to output it. Take this one step at a time.

Comment: @David Said code works, it triggers both my overlay to become invisible, at the same time when I was testing my alert function to ensure the variable was retrieving the year correctly it also displayed the alert, tldr; click button hides overlay and activated my alert box I was using for testing at the same time

Comment: @Foxhound: If the code works, what are you asking?  If it *doesn't work*, then insisting that it does isn't going to help solve the problem.

Comment: @David the main code in question is at the top, the bottom was just to help other users see the code flow and what was being passed where

Comment: @Foxhound: The main structural problem of the code in question is that you're trying to write a value to the page before that value exists.  You should output the value *inside the function*, not before the function is ever called.

Comment: @Pointy I moved the ageinyear function below mostly everything, now object Object disappears but it doesn't display still hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence of events you're defining here:

```
<script>
var age;
function ageinyear() {
    age = document.getElementById("year").value;
}
</script>

<script>document.write(age)</script>
```

*Defining* a function doesn't *invoke* a function.  So essentially the above is the same as this:

```
<script>
var age;
</script>

<script>document.write(age)</script>
```

No value is being written to the page because there's no value in that variable.  It's declared, but it's undefined.

Instead of trying to output to the page *immediately* (as in, before the user has set the value), output to the page *in the function* that gets invoked by the user setting the value.  Something like this:

```
<script>
var age;
function ageinyear() {
    age = document.getElementById("year").value;
    document.getElementById("yearOutput").textContent = age;
}
</script>

<span id="yearOutput"></span>
```

Comment: Well done man, thanks for the explanation, my main issue here was the order and you helped me sort it, thank you!

Comment: @Foxhound: It took a little back-and-forth to get here, but glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

By prefixing the variable `age` with the `var` keyword the variable is declared only in the scope of the `<script>` element which contains it. To get what you have to work then you could declare the variable in the global scope by removing the `var` keyword.

```
<script>
    age ={}; // declare the variable in the global scope - can access it anywhere
    function ageinyear() {
        age = document.getElementById("year").value;
    }
</script>


<h3 id="userWelcome"><span id="splitColorHeading">
    Welcome <script> document.write(age)</script>,</span> to THE SESH
</h3>
```

Comment: To **declare** the variable globally would be `var age;`, as in the OP. Your change will not make any difference; `age` will still be an object reference.

Comment: This would still print `[object Object]` because `ageinyear` is never called in the shown code, so at the time `document.write(age)` is executed, `age` is still `{}` and an `Object` as of that.

Comment: @Pointy this worked for purpose, however the HTML loaded, therefore didn't take affect in overwriting what is still [object Object]

Comment: @t.niese yes this exactly!

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, misunderstood the question. My fault :(

Comment: @phuzi Thanks for the help though, what you said did rid the code of errors, so +1 for that and explanation

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet below you take an input from your HTML, you can make some computation on it depending on your use case and then, you modify an HTML element.

```html
<h3 id="change">to change</h3>
<input id="age" type="number"/>
<button onclick="change()">change</button>

<script>
function change() {
        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        //make a computation
        parseInt(age) + 1
        document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "hello" + age
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to print **object** directly when you write document.write(age) the age variable is called age.toString() which return [object object]. 
Use

```
document.write(JSON.stringify(age))
```